# trying to add an service to my angularjs app

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to add a service to my app and can not see the problem. I must be missing something simple.

My App definition looks like: (lots of stuff removed in the service). The service will also be moved to a separate file once i figure out what i am doing wrong. That is why in this example it is a separate call;

```
var app =   angular.module('app', ['ngRoute','ngResource', 'ngAnimate', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.tree', 'ngMap', 'ngTagsInput', 'angular-loading-bar', 'app.controllers'
                             , 'app.directives', 'app.localization', 'app.nav', 'app.ui.ctrls', 'app.ui.directives'
                             , 'app.ui.services', 'app.ui.map', 'app.form.validation', 'app.ui.form.ctrls', 'app.ui.form.directives', 'app.tables', 'app.task'
                             , 'app.chart.ctrls', 'app.chart.directives', 'app.page.ctrls'
                             , 'virtualAssistServices'
                            ]
                      );
angular.module('app')
       .service('virtualAssistServices', ['$http', function ($http) {
                var urlBase = '/api/customers';

 }]);
```

if I remove virtualAssistServices from the app definition every works fine, but as soon as i add to the app module i get the error

```
Error: [$injector:modulerr] Failed to instantiate module app due to: [$injector:modulerr] 
Failed to instantiate module virtualAssistServices due to: [$injector:nomod] Module
'virtualAssistServices' is not available! You either misspelled the module name or 
forgot to loadit. If registering a module ensure that you specify the dependencies 
as the second argument.
 http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.27/$injector/nomod?p0=virtualAssistServices
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't mention `virtualAssistServices` in dependencies array of your `app` definition, because `virtualAssistServices` is not a module.

You are defining the service on the app module itself. So inherently that service functionality is attached to the app.

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't list `virtualAssistServices` in the array when you assign the app. That's for listing modules that you depend on; you don't list your own services there.

Answer (score 0):

Your services should go to controller instead of a module, if created as part of same module. If service is created in a different module, add the dependency in module.

```
app.controller('MyController', [ '$scope', 'virtualAssistServices', function($scope, virtualAssistServices) {

});
```